# Should we agree on a set duplicate for "is this notated correctly" questions?

Tags: discussion

I've seen an up-tick in questions recently asking if a particular rhythmic notation is ideal, and what a better practice might be (if there is one). Consider, for example, [Dotted or tied quarter on beat two?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/75940/dotted-or-tied-quarter-on-beat-two)

After answering the above question, I started wondering if there was a good duplicate we could point to for questions like this in the future.

The best I've found is [What is the clearest way to notate this rhythm?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/59258/what-is-the-clearest-way-to-notate-this-rhythm/). I find Michael Seifert's answer brilliant and really clear.

If this is a democracy, and if we agree that we should begin marking these questions as duplicates, I'll recommend this to be the set duplicate, even if it's not the earliest appearance of this problem (or even the highest-voted answer). I'd love to hear suggestions from others, if there are any.

Comment: Are there any questions that are good examples of what you mean that have been closed as duplicates?

Comment: @topomorto No, because we haven't been closing them as duplicates. But other examples include https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/75940/dotted-or-tied-quarter-on-beat-two and https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/75146/imaginary-bar-line-fixed

Comment: Thanks - I was just wondering how far we'd gone down the close-as-duplicate road so far.

Comment: Does anyone know whether we have "set duplicates" for other types of questions?

Answer (score 4):

I do agree that a nice solid duplicate will help us a lot here, though I'm not sure that the current question "What is the clearest way to notate this rhythm?" is the right one for this. The answer is beautiful and show how there is an objectivity root in this type of notation, but the question itself is not ideal for getting the point across that the answers inside are of general use.

Ideally the canonical duplicate to this will talk about the general method of determining when to tie vs use the note value and explain it in detail with a few common time signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I like this idea! Obviously it can only extend to rhythm notation questions. I'm fine with that question being the marked duplicate example, though I'm open to other suggestions *(perhaps one with examples in sheet music form?)*. I'd also like to know how we can implement this. Would people who flagged as duplicates be shown an option to link to that example or something?